# Problems loading the labvel at the start

Tags: c#, logic

I'm making a program that just displays the Code of the day at my school. but there is a problem with the way the label I'm using loads. The label starts off displaying "label1" and only changes to the Code of the day when I click on it. Can anyone figure out what is wrong. here is a snippet of the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private string GetCOTD()
        {
            //a function for getting the the COTD
            string sourceString = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("http://guestwifi.discoveryschool.org.uk/cotd/?id=01234");
            sourceString = sourceString.Substring(959, 8);
            return sourceString;
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = GetCOTD();
        }
        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = GetCOTD();
        }

        private void label1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = GetCOTD();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can convert it online, for example here [Telerik](http://converter.telerik.com/). But I would suggest trying it yourself first and see how far you get.

Comment: @Saragis ill try the converter. seriously I don't really know either language. but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are, on the form, create a text control such as my richtextbox, subscribe load event, call the converted function, and enjoy:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.Text = (string)GetCOTD();
    }

    private object GetCOTD()
    {
        //a function for gettinthe the COTD
        string sourceString = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("http://www.w3schools.com/");
        sourceString = sourceString.Substring(959, 8);
        return sourceString;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The converters will give you funky code because the original VB function didn't specify a return type (therefore it was simply returning Object).

Here's what it should have looked like in VB:

```
Private Function GetCOTD() As String
    Dim sourceString As String = New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("http://guestwifi.discoveryschool.org.uk/cotd/?id=01234")
    Return sourceString.Substring(959, 8)
End Function
```

In C#:

```
    private string GetCOTD()
    {
        string sourceString = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("http://guestwifi.discoveryschool.org.uk/cotd/?id=01234");
        return sourceString.Substring(959, 8);
    }
```